# Normalizing a function to have an area of 1 in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to normalize a function so that the area under it is 1. I found some MATLAB code, converted most of it to R, but I can't seem to figure out the final normalization part in R. This is what I have so far:

```
probs <- c(0,1,10,2,0,0,4,5,3,1,0)
x <- 1:length(probs)
k <- splinefun(x,probs)
plot(x,probs)
p0 <- curve(k(x), add=T, col = 2, n = 1001)
#BAD CODE: p0 <- p0/sum(p0)
```

Comment: You want `p0$y/sum(p0$y)` I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Function `curve` returns a list. You need to extract the `y` from your object `p0`.

```
probs <- c(0,1,10,2,0,0,4,5,3,1,0)
x <- 1:length(probs)
k <- splinefun(x,probs)
plot(x,probs)
p0 <- curve(k(x), add=TRUE, col = 2, n = 1001)
names(p0)
# [1] "x" "y"
class(p0)
# [1] "list"
sum(p0$y)
# [1] 2494.255
sum(p0$y/sum(p0$y))
# [1] 1
```